# ALPHA VANTAGE stock and forex API, I want to extract data for the differences between gld stock and xau forex

Tags: python, stock

It gives me GLD information but not XAU. This is my code:

```
import time
import requests

API_KEY = "In my real code I have a working api key"
SYMBOLS = ["XAU", "GLD"]

# Function to get the current price from the Alpha Vantage API

def get_price(symbol):
    if symbol == "XAU":
        url = f"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=USD&to_currency=XAU&apikey={API_KEY}"
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        
        if "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate" in data:
            return data["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"]["5. Exchange Rate"]
        else:
            print("Error fetching exchange rate for XAU")
            return None
    elif symbol == "GLD":
        url = f"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=GLD&apikey={API_KEY}"
        response = requests.get(url)
        data = response.json()
        
        return data["Global Quote"]["05. price"]
    else:
        return None




# Function to write data to the text file
def write_to_file(filename, content):
    with open(filename, "a") as f:
        f.write(content)

# Main program loop
while True:
    current_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    for symbol in SYMBOLS:
        price = get_price(symbol)
        if price is not None:
            data = f"{current_time} - {symbol} Price: {price}\n"
            write_to_file("prices.txt", data)
        else:
            print(f"Error fetching price for {symbol}")
    
    # Wait for 10 minutes
    time.sleep(600)  # 10 minutes = 600 seconds
```

I tried using two API calls but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean that `get_price("XAU")` just doesn't work? (Then the problem would be unrelated to "two API calls")

Comment: It just gives me the information for GLD and for xau it says couldn't get data

Comment: Do you mean that it says "Error fetching exchange rate for XAU"? Because "couldn't get data" is not in your code.